# Best way to find a no-surcharge ATM in my area?

Tags: united-states, fees, withdrawal, atm

Is there any easy way to find an ATM, by location search, that doesn't have any surcharges? The closest thing I could find to a generalized solution is sponsored by [All Point](http://www.allpointnetwork.com/atm-locators.aspx), so it only returns their own ATM locations.

Comment: every ATM card I have seen has a list of logos that specify the networks they work with, some of these are surcharge free.

Comment: Even if the ATM doesn't charge a surcharge, your bank will likely charge you for not using their own ATMs. So the place to start with this is an ATM locator provided by your banking institutions. After that, look around for credit unions as they're less likely to surcharge non-customers.

Comment: I'm now thinking there is no such thing as "surcharge free" for ATMs outside of your network. Even these All Point ATMs, which advertise themselves as surcharge fee, will charge a surcharge if you're not in their network (I just tried one locally).

Comment: There are two kinds of surcharges.  One is charged by your bank for letting you withdraw money from an ATM not in their network.  The other is charged by the ATM operator for letting you use the ATM.  Even if AllPoint doesn't charge you the latter fee, your own bank may be charging you the former for using that ATM.

Comment: @BrenBarn I am aware of the difference. AllPoint is indeed charging me the latter fee.

Comment: Is https://m.greendot.com/storelocator.aspx?t=locations&LocationType=atm helpful?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a credit union, I look for the co-op network credit union ATMs.   Wide network of fee-free ATMs: http://co-opcreditunions.org/locator/?ref=co-opatm.org&sc=1

You'll have to check with your bank or credit union to see what networks they belong to and if it isn't satisfactory to you, find a new bank or credit union.

Comment: If you aren't using a credit union, every credit card network I've tried has an "ATM finder" on its website. Look at your card to see which networks the bank has registered with, and check with those to see if any of them promise to be fee-free. The SUM network is one such; there may be others. Of course you'll also want to check which networks your own bank will or won't charge a fee for using

Answer (score 0):

This only indirectly answer your question, but Schwab investor checking account has no fee, no minimum balance, and will reimburse all ATM fee (inside and outside the US)

Answer (score 0):

Get a checking account with Ally Bank. They refund all ATM fees from within the US, so effectively, every ATM transaction will have no surcharge.

Answer (score 0):

Some Walmart stores have a surcharge-free ATM in their Money Center. If that doesn't work, look for the logo of the interbank network on the back of your card that your bank uses (e.g. Star, Cirrus, Allpoint, MoneyPass) and Google them. If you're lucky, they'll have a surcharge-free ATM locator (e.g. https://www.star.com/locator/).